# Can't drop table on Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms, drop-table

I am new to working with Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, and it is not letting me drop a table that I have created. I need to modify its primary keys, but it freezes when I try to do that as well and when I try to save the file it freezes. I've run sp_who2'active' and it doesnt appear to have anything blocking it from being deleted or saved. Also tried running the command DROP TABLE and it ran for 2 minutes and didnt execute anything. Any help appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Could be a problem with the disk. I can't say for sure, but at one point I set up a database on a bad disk of mine, and dropping tables, procedures and eventually the database took hours.

Comment: Try TRUNCATE TABLE before dropping your table and compare the result.

Comment: Thank you! I think I have a bad disk.

Comment: Make sure you check the "Drop Connections" box in the delete table dialog.

Comment: In my case, this only happened with users who were not System Admins. You might need to adjust permissions both inside and outside of SQL